# groovy split docker image url

Tags: url, groovy, split

I have a variable in groovy that contains a docker Image path like

```
def myDockerImage='docker.example.com:50001/something/more/here:myImagTag'
```

Now I want split the variable in order to replace the the servername:port by another server url. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like so:

```
String replaceServer(String newServer, String dockerImage) {
    def (_, image) = dockerImage.split('/', 2)
    "$newServer/$image"
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
def myDockerImage='docker.example.com:50001/something/more/here:myImagTag'

def newDockerImage = replaceServer('my.new.server.com:8080', myDockerImage)
```